# Java/ Android Studio equivalent of C# / Xamarin 'public event Action varName'

Tags: java, c#, android, android-studio, xamarin

I was asked to port a code from Xamarin to Android studio (C# to java) and I'm struggling in porting several things, amongst them ' public event Action varName1 ' and their implementation to java. On

Xamarin they are used as followed:

```
public class class1: Java.Lang.Object{

public event Action varName1;
public event Action varName2;
...

//and they are called as 

varName1();
varName2();
//on the public void OnMove(MotionEvent motionEvent) method.

}
```

also, they are used on

```
class2:Activity{
void initialization()
  {
        class1 listener = new class1();

    listener.varName1 += class3.Open;
    listener.varName2 += class3.Close;
...
}
```

So I assume that each can be broken down into two requirements, an event and an Action with no parameters. Since Action is from System, and as far as I have seen there is no direct port, I made thought of makin use of a code found at http://codingbytodesign.net/en/2016/06/06/actiont-and-funct-tresult-in-java-8/.

I've also read about events and how to work with them in java and found this to be very helpful ( https://scatteredcode.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/from-c-to-java-events/), but when trying to sort both things out I don't even know where to start.

I believe I might be overcomplicating things, so I would love to recieve some guidance or if someone can help me with an example on how to solving this I would be more than grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct translation of that. What Java usually does is to implement Listener Interfaces, which are simple callbacks.

So your example could be written somewhat like:

```
public interface MyListener {
   public void action1();
   public void action2();
}
```

Then your class could have a constructor which takes this interface as argument and invokes it later:

```
public class ListenerConsumer {
    MyListener listener;
    ListenerConsumer (MyListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        this.listener.action1();
    }

    public void doSomethingElse() {
        this.listener.action2();
    }
}
```

You could then implement the `MyListener` class anonymously when constructing the `ListenerConsumer` like:

```
ListenerConsumer derp = new ListenerConsumer(new MyListener() {
    @Override
    public void action1() {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Hello action1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void action1() {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Hello action2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

or

Comment: Thanks for the answer Cheesebaron. I think I can more or less understand what you are saying. But to assign to action1() and action2() (or reference) to another method as ' listener.action1() += class3.Open(); ' , is it possible ? Or should the method be called insidethe ' @Override  action1() ?

Comment: You would call that in the overridden action1().

Comment: Thanks for your help Cheesebaron! Another question,  if in c# I have subscribed to an event through 

obj.event+= handler;

where the 'event' is a event Action<int> and the 'handler' is void handler(int index), is there a way to subscribe a method to an event in java? Or should I call the event in an override as well where needed?

Comment: Java does not have events. Just callbacks or as shown above listeners, which are Interfaces you implement...